# Is it normal to max out zenny nearly 15 hours into MHGU?

Tags: monster-hunter-generations-ultimate

Is it normal to max out your zenny currency so easily in Monster Hunter Generations Ultimate? This is only my first monster hunter game ever and I only just got the game less than a week ago. Am I some kind of natural God at this game or is zenny just extremely easy to come by? I kept earning these steel, silver, gold, platinum etc eggs that were worth a truck load of zenny and apparently the only use for them is to sell, so basically it was just easy money.[image]

Comment: Considering the games entire DLC's have already been realeased, thus giving you a ton of valueables from the get go I'd guess it's fairly easy to max your money. But I am too occupied to do the math.

Comment: That's what I initially thought when I collected a bunch of free rewards, but all the DLC and rewards and what not only gave me something like 200,000 zenny at the most. But I reached 9,999,999 zenny purely through playing a few quests and earning lots of valuable eggs as rewards so the DLC and extra content included was only a small portion of the money I earned.